# Construct tree given root

Tags: python

ex. `[13,11], [13,8], [6, 8], [3, 6]`
where the root is 1

Looking for a Pythonic way to construct a tree into a dictionary such that we then have `{13: [11, 8], 11: [], 3: [], 6: [3], 8: [6]}`

Since I know the root, the way I would approach is to loop through entries with 13, connect those, then treating those entries as root, so and so forth.

Note there is no ordering. To distinguish between, I know the root (some number) and can determine from there.

Is there a better way?

Comment: Should have noted there's no ordering ex. first entry is a parent, second is a child. So 8 is actually the parent of 5 but child of 1. To distinguish between, I know the root and can determine from there.

Comment: Can you have repeated elements in the tree?

Comment: Nope ----------

Comment: Can you have circular dependencies? Like a cycle in the graph?

Comment: No cycles, it's a tree, acyclic

Comment: Can you post some of the larger trees just for validation?

Comment: You changed the example, but you didn't change the root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most pythonic way I can think, also the fastest one is the following:

```
def dfs(es, s):
    graph = {}
    for x, y in es:
        graph.setdefault(x, set()).add(y)
        graph.setdefault(y, set()).add(x)

    tree, stack = {}, [s]
    while stack:
        parent = stack.pop()
        children = graph[parent] - tree.keys()
        tree[parent] = list(children)
        stack.extend(children)
    return tree

edges = [[1, 2], [5, 8], [1, 8], [3, 5]]
print(dfs(edges, 1))
```

**Output**

```
{8: [5], 1: [8, 2], 2: [], 3: [], 5: [3]}
```

The above approach is linear in the size of the graph `O(N + E)` where `N` is the number of nodes and `E` is the number of edges. A simpler approach, albeit slower is:

```
egdes = [[1, 2], [1, 8], [5, 8], [3, 5]]
tree = {}
sources = {1}


while sources:
    parent = sources.pop()
    children = [t for s, t in egdes if (s == parent and t not in tree)] + \
               [s for s, t in egdes if (t == parent and s not in tree)]
    tree[parent] = children
    sources.update(children)

print(tree)
```

**Output**

```
{8: [5], 1: [2, 8], 2: [], 3: [], 5: [3]}
```

A faster approach is to delete the already seen edges:

```
while sources:
    parent = sources.pop()
    children = [y if x == parent else x for x, y in edges if parent in (x, y)]
    edges = [edge for edge in edges if parent not in edge]
    tree[parent] = children
    sources.update(children)
```

**Output**

```
{8: [5], 1: [2, 8], 2: [], 3: [], 5: [3]}
```

Answer (score 2):

By using a `set` to keep track of which elements have been added to the dictionary, we can solve this problem in O(n) time.  The general idea is to loop through the nodes, check if a node is currently in the graph, and if so, we know that it is the parent when adding to the dictionary.

```
from collections import defaultdict

class MyTree:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = defaultdict(list)
        self.seen = set()

        for node in data:
            self.add_node(node)

        for el in self.seen:
            if el not in self.data:
                self.data[el] = []

    def add_node(self, el):
        x, y = el

        if y in self.seen:
            self.data[y].append(x)
        else:
            self.data[x].append(y)

        self.seen.update(el)
```

In action:

```
arr = [[1,2], [1,8], [5, 8], [3, 5]]

x = MyTree(arr)
print(x.data)
```

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {1: [2, 8], 8: [5], 5: [3], 2: [], 3: []})
```

Answer (score 0):

A recursive approach:

```
d = [[1,2], [1,8], [5, 8], [3, 5]]
def t(d, r):
    o = {r: []}
    n = []
    for e in d:
        if r in e:
            if e[1] == r:
                e = e[::-1]
            o[e[0]].append(e[1])
        else:
            n.append(e)
    for i in o[r]:
        o.update(t(n, i))
    return o
print(t(d, 1))
```

This outputs:

```
{1: [2, 8], 2: [], 8: [5], 5: [3], 3: []}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a breadth-first search:

```
import collections
data = [[1,2], [1,8], [5, 8], [3, 5]]
def bfs(d, _start = lambda x:x[0][0]):
  _queue, _result, _seen = collections.deque([_start(d)]), collections.defaultdict(list), []
  while _queue:
    v = _queue.popleft()
    r = [i[0] if i[-1] == v else i[-1] for i in d if v in i]
    _r = [i for i in r if i not in _seen]
    _result[v].extend(_r)
    _queue.extend(_r)
    _seen.extend(_r+[v])
  return _result

print(bfs(data))
```

Output:

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {1: [2, 8], 8: [5], 5: [3], 2: [], 3: []})
```

Answer (score -1):

```
d = [[1,2], [1,8], [5, 8], [3, 5]]
def t(d, r):
    o = {r: []}
    while d:
        e = d.pop(0)
        if e[1] in o:
            e = e[::-1]
        if e[0] in o:
            o[e[0]].append(e[1])
            o[e[1]] = []
        else:
            d.append(e)
    return o
print(t(d, 1))
```

This outputs:

```
{1: [2, 8], 2: [], 8: [5], 5: [3], 3: []}
```

Comment: Breaks on larger trees

Comment: Fixed. No longer assumes that edges containing the parent always come before edges containing the children.